# What does "mezzocannone" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

[Via Mezzocannone](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Via_Mezzocannone) is the name of my street in Napoli. I wonder what it does mean. *Mezzo* means half, I guess. *Cannone*, I do not remember.

Comment: "Cannone" (surprise, surprise) means "cannon", so a literal translation would be something like "half-cannon".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the name means half cannon. The story of this name is interesting and dates back to the XV century. It is a derogatory reference to the upper part of a fountain that the King of Naples wanted in that place.

> La cannella di bronzo da cui sgorgava l’acqua, chiamata volgarmente «cannone», appariva infatti decisamente corta, un «mezzo cannone», insomma; essa era inoltre sovrastata dalla statua di un sovrano, raffigurante probabilmente lo stesso Alfonso II. Se le intenzioni iniziali erano quelle di creare una scultura che trasmettesse imponenza e regalità, le sue forme sproporzionate dovevano renderla in realtà alquanto buffa, al punto da suscitare l’ilarità del popolo, che conierà appositamente il motto burlesco «me pare ‘o Rre ‘e miezz cannon», per indicare una persona «che sia di statura men che mezzana, panciuta, rabbuffata e si dia aria di gravità», come ci spiega Gino Doria nel suo Le strade di Napoli.

<sub>**Source:** [Via Mezzocannone, all'origine del suo nome "la dissacrante ironia dei napoletani"](https://www.napolitoday.it/cronaca/via-mezzocannone-fontana-nome.html), 19 luglio 2014.</sub>